# Can only get through so many iterations of this loop?

Tags: c, linked-list, runtime

```
void append(Link *link,LList *list)
{
Link *lastLink=NULL;
lastLink=list->head;
if(lastLink!=NULL)
{
    while(lastLink->next!=NULL)
    {
        lastLink = lastLink->next;
    }
    lastLink->next=link;
}
else
{
    list->head=link;
}
list->size++;
} 

for(i=0;i<65000;i++)
{
    link=(Link*)malloc(sizeof(Link));
    link->value=i;
    append(link,list2);
    printf("%d\n",list2->size);
}
```

Above is an append function for a linked list with the associated for loop calling it. Im using the system clock to  test the runtime of this function. When it is run on its own it only goes through 8264 iterations of the loop before crashing and if it is run after a prepend function in a similar loop (65000 iterations building a different list), the append loop only gets to 508 before crashing. So it looks to be memory related but im not sure.

Comment: Is `list2` initialised correctly, can you show the code where you initialise `list2`?

Comment: Please show the rest of the code where you handle list2. And what exactly happens when it crashes? Segfault?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "crashes" you mean it segfaults.

First of all, you're not setting `link->next` to `NULL`. After allocating memory for `link`, `link->next` contains garbage values and you will lose the ability to find the end of your list.

Also, notice that you are allocating memory and never free it - you are most likely getting out of heap memory. To avoid this, you should test malloc's return value:

```
for(i=0;i<65000;i++)
{
    if ((link = malloc(sizeof(Link))) == NULL) {
        /* Out of memory */
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
        /* Handle error... */
    }
    else {
        link->value=i;
        link->next = NULL;
        append(link,list2);
        printf("%d\n",list2->size);
    }
}
```

I added `link->next = NULL` in the loop body. You may want to do it inside `append()` instead. I also removed the cast from malloc, since it is generally bad practice. If you try this and it still crashes, make sure `list2` is correctly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your Memory runs out of space. In that case malloc can't allocate Memory an returns NULL. You can test the return-value of malloc before you initialize "link":

```
if ((link = malloc(sizeof(Link))) == NULL)
{
    /* Error Handling: Memory ran out of space */
}
else
{
   link->value=i;
   append(link,list2);
   printf("%d\n",list2->size);
}
```

Another Problem is that you test "lastLink->next!=NULL" but you never initialize the next-attribute. If you allocate memory with malloc you just get the space. The content of the memory is undefined. So you should initialize the next-attribute with link->next=NULL.
Another possibility is calloc. calloc allocates memory as well as malloc, but calloc initializes the memory with 0. You could use calloc(1,sizeof(Link)). If there is not enough space in memory, calloc will return NULL.